# How to create multiple jobs from an array in PowerShell using Start-Job

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following command:

```
'a','b','c' | Start-Job { "Hello: $input" } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Hello: a b c
```

The output I was expecting is:

```
Hello: a
Hello: b
Hello: c
```

It appears that `'a','b','c' | Start-Job { "Hello: $input" }` is only creating one job for the whole input array and not one for each of the items in the array. Can someone explain why that is please, because I'm confused. I'm aware that I can re-write the thing like the following but I'm not sure why I need to, or if there is a better way:

```
'a','b','c' | ForEach-Object { $_ | Start-Job { "Hello: $input" }} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Comment: What made you think it would create a new job per input object? There is no indication in the docs that could mislead you that way

Comment: If I run 'a','b','c' | Write-Output I get output on three separate lines, not a single line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the misconception comes from but Microsoft never makes an indication that a new job would be created *per input object*, they state the following in the `Start-Job` doc:

> [`-InputObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.3#-inputobject)
> Specifies input to the command. Enter a variable that contains the objects, or type a command or expression that generates the objects.
> In the value of the ScriptBlock parameter, use the `$input` automatic variable to represent the input objects.

This parameter is essentially 1 of the 3 different ways there are to pass values to the Job's scope.

All examples produce the same outcome.

```bash
0..10 | Start-Job {
    foreach ($i in $input) { $i }
} | Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait

Start-Job {
    foreach ($i in $args) { $i }
} -ArgumentList (0..10) | Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait

$arr = 0..10; Start-Job {
    foreach ($i in $using:arr) { $i }
} | Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77052096/45375) explains the problem with your expectation of [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)'s behavior with pipeline input well.**
The explanation applies equally to the generally preferable, *thread*-based [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet, which is [installable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.ThreadJob) in *Windows PowerShell* and ships with [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).

---

While **launching a job *for each pipeline input object*** is indeed necessary if you want each object to be processed by a dedicated job, ***PowerShell (Core) 7+* offers a *direct*,  thread-based way** to implement your task, namely with **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)'s `-Parallel` parameter**:

The following is a simpler - and due to use of *thread*-based rather than *child process*-based parallelism - much faster alternative to your own `ForEach-Object` + `Start-Job` approach:

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only
'a','b','c' | ForEach-Object -Parallel { "Hello: $_" }
```

The above executes *synchronously* and *directly outputs* to the caller what the threads output (though in no guaranteed order).

If you do **need *job* behavior** - allowing you to perform foreground tasks while the threads run and to collect the results later, on demand - additionally use the **`-AsJob` switch**, which makes `ForEach-Object -Parallel` return a single job whose child jobs represent the individual threads, and which you can manage with the usual `*-Job` cmdlets:

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only
$jobs = 'a','b','c' | ForEach-Object -AsJob -Parallel { "Hello: $_" }

# ... perform other processing

# Now collect the outputs.
$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```